# Sorting all elements of matrix by ascending order in c

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

I need to sort a given matrix by ascending order (all elements).

Lets assume the give matrix is

```
2  0  4  -1
-3 1  5   5
6  4  4   9
-5 8  10  12
```

the sorted matrix should be like this:

```
-5  -3  -1  0 
1   2   4   4
4   5   5   6
8   9   10  12
```

My code gives me bad results.

When 
    k=0 w=0 
its ok it does good
it countinues
    k=0 w=1 
but then 
it jumps to
    k=1 w=1
without checking
    k=1 w=0 
because of the
    w=j
i need to replace **w** with something to fix it 
but i dont know with what to replace it

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 2

int main()
{
    int arr[n][n],min,i,j,tmp,y,k,w,z=0,q=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter number: ");
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            min=arr[i][j];
            for(k=i;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(w=j;w<n;w++)
                if(arr[k][w]<min)
                {
                    min=arr[k][w];
                    z=k;
                    q=w;
                }
                w=0;
            }
            tmp=arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j]=min;
            arr[z][q]=tmp;
        }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "bad results."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: When k=0 w=0 .. its ok it does good .. it countinues 
k=0 w=1

but then .. it jumps to k=1 w=1  .. without checking k=1 w=0
because of the **w=j**
i need to replace **w= somthing"** to fix it .. but i dont know with
what to replace it

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `w=j`. You set `w` to `0` at the end of the loop, but then you instantly set it back to `j` as you start the new loop.

An additional problem is that if `arr[i][j]` is the smallest element, `z` and `q` will essentially be rubbish values, since they are never set, they will still be what they were in the previous iteration. You need to set these as you set `min` in the beginning of the loop.

As a minor issue, you should also `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Updated code:

```
// initialize z and q
z = i;
q = j;

min = arr[i][j];

// set w here
w = j;

for (k = i; k < n; k++)
{
    // don't set w here
    for (; w < n; w++)
    if (arr[k][w] < min)
    {
        min = arr[k][w];
        z = k;
        q = w;
    }
    w = 0;
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/WmWTM6).

Comment: still same bad results

Comment: am sure it's the latest version ... it still gives bad results

Comment: `int main(void){... return 0;}` for a runtime-error result free ideone code :)

Comment: @another.anon.coward Oh right, thanks. Didn't see that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional problem( Dukeling's method is right at the other problem).

In every loop's end, you assign the value of `arr[i][j]` to `arr[z][q]` . If You don't find a smaller element, `z` and `q` still hold the value from the previous loop and You make the swap(or an assingment). You need to check if you've found an element smaller than the actual (`arr[i][j]`) element.

The not nicest solution:

```
if ( arr[z][q] < arr[i][j] )
{
    tmp=arr[i][j];
    arr[i][j]=min;
    arr[z][q]=tmp;
}
```

Comment: Your fix doesn't work 100%, see [this](http://ideone.com/eO7cBi) for an example.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, You're right, beacuse in some case, z and q are uninitialized. With initialization `z=q=0` at the beginning of the code, it should work fine(in some cases with less assingments than your everytime-swap method).

Comment: `z` and `q` are already set to `0` at the beginning of the code in the example I linked. I suspect the problem comes in when a swap *did not* occur during the previous iteration.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, I can see it now, Thank You for the correction!